# db-scheduler - how to remove picked scheduled tasks

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, scheduler

I need help to find the way to delete scheduled tasks even if they currently picked.
db-scheduler throws TaskInstanceCurrentlyExecutingException “Cannot use SchedulerClient to modify a task-instance that is currently executing. If this occurs often, consider only modifying executions not picked that has the next execution-time a certain time into the future”, when I'm trying to delete scheduled task which is currently executing. Mb someone faced the same issue?

db-scheduler uses MySql table to monitor scheduled task. Mb I could just delete data about this task from db. Will be the current execution the last one in such case? This solution is suitable too.
Currently I use cancel(TaskInstanceId taskInstanceId) method from Scheduler.class to delete tasks which throws TaskInstanceCurrentlyExecutingException

I tried to find something in [db-scheduler](https://github.com/kagkarlsson/db-scheduler) documentation, but there is no result.